# Size of div tags with an image - html5 with JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, css, html

I use this statement to get a background image inside the div tag.

```
 <div data-role="content" data-theme="a" style= "height:100%; background:url    
('./images/tankanzeige.png') center center no-repeat">  
</div>
```

I want to have the div be the same size as the image, but it has the wrong size it shows only 20% percent of the image.

What do I have to change?

Comment: So you want to have the div resize itself to the size of the background image you apply to it?

Comment: Yeah something like that! I simply wanna show the image with it's right size, inside the div. Isn't that possible?

Comment: Well I assume you want it as a background image for a reason rather than just putting it in the div (because that would show it all) and I assume you also cannot guarantee what size the image will be or you could just put height:250px; for example, but I think this would need to be done in JQuery rather than CSS. let me think of the answer

Comment: I know the size of the image and the reason why I want to use it as background image is beacause I want to drwa with a canvas on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you want to resize the `div` to fit the image:**

**1.** If you know the size of the image then you must set the pixel size of the div - e.g. 100px height and 200px width:

```
<div data-role="content" data-theme="a" style= "height:100px; width: 200px; background:url('./images/tankanzeige.png') center center no-repeat">  
</div>
```

That's because `20%` means - "try to take 20% of the parent".

**2.** It is much easier to use an image tag `<img>` inside the div as this will allow the div to expand automatically.

**3.** If you must use the CSS background image and you don't know the image size, you need to use JavaScript to get the image size. First you need to create a new `Image` object.

See this answer: [how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/626505/206614)

and the code from it:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  alert(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
}
img.src = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif';
```

Please note, you need the `onload` event to allow the image to load first.

---

**If you want to resize the CSS background to fit the div:**

You can use the CSS3 property `background-size: 100%;`

Comment: Thanks your first approach is right. The image is shown. But its not centered anymore. Why is that?

Comment: You mean the image is not centered? Or the `div` is not centered? If you set the size of the div to equal the size of the image then their centers should exactly overlap. Centering the `div` depends on its parent. Try setting `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` on the div

Answer (score 0):

The entire image will show in the div as long as the image is smaller than the window size. In its simplified form (the code in your question) the div will take up the entire window.

So, if your image is not showing, it is too big to fit the available space. You can set a `min-height` and `min-width` attributes on the div to make the the full size of the image make the page scroll as necessary.

[See demo](http://www.cssdesk.com/FXHCT)

Comment: No its only about half the screen. I think the problem is JQuery Mobile! Because there is a header at the top and a footer at the bottom. But there is nothing big in it. Something strange: If I add <br><br> and a canvas inside the <div></div> it shows the whole image! Whats the matter here?